# vscode dotnet build clean - specify solution to clean error MSB1011

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm trying to use vscode to debug a solution that contains a c# project.

My tasks.json file contains the following task:

```json
    {
      "label": "clean (functions)",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "clean",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "type": "process",
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
```

When I hit debug from the debug extension, I get the following error:

> error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because
> this folder contains more than one project or solution file

How can I amend the tasks.json file to give the name of the solution to build?

Answer (score 0):

What I am using for my Azure Functions debug session is

```json
    {
      "label": "clean (functions)",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "clean",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
      ],
      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Project/XXX/XXX.Functions
      }
    }
```

the [${workspaceFolder}](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables) is your workspace folder followed by the folder where the functions are located.